# Elasticsearch memory problems

Tags: java, ubuntu, memory, elasticsearch

When I'm trying too start the elasticsearch in my Ubuntu the startup script gives me the following error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x74800000, 201326592, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 201326592 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

I try already to search by this and I couldn't find the solution for this. If I restart the machine everything work well for a day and then the elasticsearch goes down and appear this error.

I already setup the property bootstrap.mlockall: true in the elasticsearch.yml file, and also the properties in the default elasticsearch file:

```
ES_HEAP_SIZE=512 (I have 1GB of RAM)
MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited
```

Someone know what I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: Feels like you OS is having serieus memory issues, can you check the os logs? Maybe more information there about what is happening based on other processes. Also check options in relation to the mlockall: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/setup-configuration.html. Are you sure you are running only one node of elasticsearch on the server? Nothing else running on the same box?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For the current version of **elastic (5.X)** you can configure [jvm startup options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/heap-size.html) in the `jvm.options` file usually located under directory `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`:

```
-Xms1g -Xmx1g
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 84):

You have configured a virtual machine with 1 GB of RAM, but elastic is trying to start with 2 GB of RAM (default for Elasticsearch version 5.X)

Either give more memory to your VM, or change Elasticsearch [JVM settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/heap-size.html) `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options` and lower the values of the following parameters: `-Xms512m -Xmx512m`

Comment: Here's a useful thread in-case anyone else is running it in docker https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker/issues/43

Comment: On my EC2 download, the jvm.options file is in config folder

Comment: Thanks. In a Laravel Homestead project, `composer update` was causing "PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 922755072) (tried to allocate 83886080 bytes)", and I found via `htop` that `elasticsearch` (which I never intentionally installed and have never used) was hogging RAM. I edited these params (`sudo vim /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`) and then ran `vagrant reload --provision` Then `composer update` worked. Probably another solution could have been to increase from `memory: 2048` in my Homestead.yaml.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start elasticsearch by the following parameters:
`./bin/elasticsearch -Xmx512m -Xms512`

However it seems your memory (1G) is too low for running elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally elastic search jvm needs more memory for faster processing and querying multiple shards. However, the jvm size should not be more than the system memory size. Change the memory for elastic search as per your configuration in

/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options:

-Xms4g (Minimum memory)
-Xmx4g (Maximum memory)

Set it to the exactly half of the machine memory for ideal use

Answer (score 1):

In **windows** you can edit **C:\ProgramData\Elastic\ElastiSearch\config\jvm.option** file to change the size of JVM Heap (arguments: **-Xms15g** **-Xmx15g**), reducing the memory consumption.