# Elasticsearch fails to start on EC2 AMI

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

Executed the command: sudo service elasticsearch restart

```
Stopping elasticsearch:                                    [FAILED]
Starting elasticsearch:                                    [  OK  ]
[ec2-user@ip-10-237-177-6 bin]$ Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000736260000, 2312765440, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)


There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 2312765440 bytes for committing reserved memory.
An error report file with more information is saved as:
/tmp/hs_err_pid11958.log
```

Checked the Java Version:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-237-177-6 bin]$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Java config for memory:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-237-177-6 bin]$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
 intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0                                   {pd product}
uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                                   {product}
uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 65011712                            {product}
uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 1038090240                          {product}
 intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024                                {pd product}
 intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024                                {pd product}
```

Comment: It looks like your trying to allocate ~2GB of memory.  The MaxHeapSize is ~1GB.

Comment: @stdunbar: how to increase the MaxHeapSize ? via cli

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447434/elasticsearch-memory-problems/41662868#41662868