# Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: elasticsearch

Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

output of journalctl -xe

```
May 07 09:06:17 sshd[437202]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=234.32.133.34.bc.googleusercontent.com  user=root
May 07 09:06:19 sshd[437202]: Failed password for root from 34.133.32.234 port 51340 ssh2
May 07 09:06:19 sshd[437202]: Connection closed by 34.133.32.234 port 51340 [preauth]
```

output of sudo systemctl status elasticsearch

```
May 09 20:11:09 systemd-entrypoint[3380]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000080000000, 2147483648, 0) failed; error='Not enough space' (errno=12)
May 09 20:11:09 systemd-entrypoint[3380]: at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOption.flagsFinal(JvmOption.java:119)
May 09 20:11:09 systemd-entrypoint[3380]: at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOption.findFinalOptions(JvmOption.java:81)
May 09 20:11:09 systemd-entrypoint[3380]: at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.choose(JvmErgonomics.java:38)
May 09 20:11:09 systemd-entrypoint[3380]: at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.jvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:135)
May 09 20:11:09 systemd-entrypoint[3380]: at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:86)
May 09 20:11:09 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 09 20:11:09 systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
May 09 20:11:09 systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
May 09 20:11:09 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.
```

jvm.options

```
################################################################
##
## The heap size is automatically configured by Elasticsearch
## based on the available memory in your system and the roles
## each node is configured to fulfill. If specifying heap is
## required, it should be done through a file in jvm.options.d,
## and the min and max should be set to the same value. For
## example, to set the heap to 4 GB, create a new file in the
## jvm.options.d directory containing these lines:
##
-Xms128m
-Xmx128m
##
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to running out of Memory.

Could you please to share the memory allocated to this ES instance and if you did change the jvm.options.

take a look to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447434/elasticsearch-memory-problems)

Comment: I have edited the main question and added output

Comment: -Xms128m
-Xmx128m

Comment: Hi, Is this setting ok for jvm.options ?

Comment: Hi, how much ram do you have? because the JVM you configured is too low. I don't know how it will work.